# Functional dependency if XY-->XZ then Y-->Z?

Tags: database, postgresql, functional-dependencies

I know that if Y-->Z then XY-->XZ but does it work the other way? That is, if XY-->XZ then does that mean Y-->Z?

Is this true or false? and how do I justify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider for istance a relation Person with attributes SSN, Name, BirthDate, where SSN is unique, and Name and BirthDate can be not unique. The following FD holds in this relation:

```
SSN, Name → SSN, BirthDate
```

but from this you cannot infer that:

```
Name → BirthDate
```

since different persons with the same name could have different birth dates.

What is true is the so called *decomposition* rule:

{x → YZ} ⊢ X → Y

So, for instance, from

```
SSN → Name, BirthDate
```

you can safely derive:

```
SSN → BirthDate
```